# Get SQL from transaction before commit

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, transactions

I am developing a project in C# with a SQL Server database.

I want to save some information in the database when a query has any conditions, so my idea was have a generic method that launches the commit of the transaction and, if the commit has the conditions required, saves the information.

My question: is there any way to obtain the SQL code of the transaction just before the `.commit()`?

For example, something like that:

```
public void insertInfo(object)
{
     using (Context context = new Context())
     {
         [Do an insert]
         [Do a second insert]
         [Do an update]     

         context.Save()
     }
} 

// In the Context
public void Save()
{
    [Here I want to get the SQL statement(s) that will be affected by the "transaction.Commit()"]
   transaction.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no built-in command or function that gets the current code of the transaction.

You could build it yourself, by creating a string variable, and every time you execute a command in the function you add it to the variable, and then read the variable when you commit the transaction.